Can't get face to Fill
I am newer to Blender (been in Sketchup world for a while) and cannot seem to get a face to fill.
All of the vertices that I select at at the same Z height, so shouldn't it fill in as a flat surface? Been trying ⇧ Shift + Alt to select edges and filling and it only fills part of the area, and also outside of the area.
Basically this is the only hole in the model.



maybe remesh the mesh with the Quad option, select the edge and Alt F to fill?

Are you actually selecting all the vertices you need? Your screenshots don't show that.
